# CSS JS Display none alter div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a one pager. And in that one pager, I have an item that is set as `display:none` (fixed side nav in a div).

Can I have it show when scrolling to a certain div?

So it starts out in the code but not displayed, and then when the user scrolls to `#about` can the side nav show up?

Comment: can you show markup or provide a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: This code makes showing a div when scrolling sound easy. http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you will need to check if the user has scrolled to or beyond the div id of about. 
First you will need to establish the current Y value of the div.

```
//cache about div
var about = $('#about');
//this caches the about div position on window load
var aboutPosition = about.position();
```

Next you will need to determine how far the the user has scrolled. The best way I have determined to accomplish this is with a timer. You could use the scoll event but its far too taxing on the user browser and a timer will be for the most part indistinguishable.

```
//generic timer set to repeat every 10 mili(very fast) 
//with a callback to execute the logic
var checkScrollPos = window.setInterval("scrollTopLogic()",10);

function scrollTopLogic(){
    //if about y position is greater than or equal to the 
    //current window scroll position do something
    if(aboutPosition.y >= $(window).scrollTop()){
        $('nav').show();
        //remove timer since it is no longer needed
        window.clearInterval(checkScrollPos);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the scroll event of the div and show the element like this

```
$("#div").scroll(function() {
   $("#item").show();
});
```